# Can't make a Python socket blocking

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to write a fairly simple client-server Python application using socket and SocketServer. To allow for two-way communication between client and server, the client maintains one connected socket with the server so it can listen for messages in a separate thread, while the main thread creates one-time-use sockets to send messages to the server. I want my "listening" socket to be blocking, as it is running in a separate thread whose only purpose is to wait for data without blocking the main program. Here is the function where I create this socket:

```
def connect(self, alias, serverIP):
    if not alias or not isinstance(alias, str):
        print "ERROR: Must specify an alias"
        return
    self.serverIP = serverIP

    self.downConnection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.downConnection.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.downConnection.setblocking(1)
    self.downConnection.connect((self.serverIP, 11100))
    self.downConnection.send("SENDSERVER CONNECT %s" % alias)
```

Here is the loop where the persistent socket listens for messages from the server (with some debugging code thrown in):

```
i = 0
while True:
    print "LOOP", i,
    if self.closed:
        break
    try:
        data = self.downConnection.recv(1024)
    except socket.timeout, e:
        print "Timeout"
        pass
    else:
        print "Received %d" % len(data)
        if data:
            self.received(data)
    i += 1
```

I would expect to see "Received ##" messages only when the server sends data, and maybe periodic "Timeout" messages otherwise. Instead, the output grows very rapidly and looks entirely like this:

```
LOOP 33858 Received 0
LOOP 33859 Received 0
LOOP 33860 Received 0
LOOP 33861 Received 0
LOOP 33862 Received 0
LOOP 33863 Received 0
LOOP 33864 Received 0
LOOP 33865 Received 0
```

So it seems that self.downConnection.recv() is immediately returning an empty string each time it is called, rather than blocking until it receives substantive data like it's supposed to. This is puzzling, as I'm explicitly setting the socket to be blocking (which I think is also the default setting). Constantly executing this loop instead of the thread spending most of its time waiting for data is wasting a good deal of CPU time. What am I doing wrong in setting up the blocking socket?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/iSjzDSp1) is the full server code. The Comms class is also the superclass of the client class, to allow for some basic common functionality.

Something does seem to be wrong with the connection from the server's end. The server can receive data from the client, but trying to send data to the client gives a `socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` exception.

Comment: First: sockets are blocking by default. Second: `recv` returning 0 means that the other side has closed the connection, i.e. that it will not send any more data and blocking would not magically send the server data. Thus your server probably behaves differently than your client expects. Unfortunately no *relevant* server code is shown.

Comment: Do you mean `recv` returning ''? The server does not close the connection on its end and holds onto it; I have updated my initial post with this code.

Comment: First of all, calling `server_bind` and `server_activate` is not required. Second, It is would very helpful if you would give us the full server code (the code for the actual handler).

Comment: Using `SocketServer`, the client handler must derive from `BaseRequestHandler` and override the `handle` method.  You don't show that code.  If you return from the `handle` method the client socket is closed.  It should normally have some kind of loop handling messages from the client until the client closes the connection, then you can return from `handle`.  Do you do this?

Comment: Link to full server code added

Comment: I'm pretty sure the sever is closing the client connection at some point; closing it manually and immediately trying to send something produces the same error. But I can't see how this is possible, since the connection isn't having its close() method called and it isn't passing out of scope at any point.

Comment: I think I found it: the TCPServer class automatically shuts down and closes client connection requests after handling them. (This is not in the SocketServer documentation, hence my confusion as I expected the connection to stay open) Disabling this behavior causes the server and client to work as I intended. I'm confused, though, as to how the server can maintain multiple connections on a port while listening on that same port. Is this possible because I set the SO_REUSEADDR flag?